# Isn't Net Domestic Product(NDP) a better metric than Gross Domestic Product(GDP)?

Tags: gdp, national-income

As per my understand we deduct depreciation from GDP, since capital goods were already counted in their year of production, we subtract depreciation so as to prevent double counting. So why is GDP a more widely used metric than NDP?

Comment: Better by what criteria, and with what objectives in mind? Depending on what you are interested in one might be better than other.

Comment: I can't find any scenarios where GDP would be better than NDP, since GDP includes double counting, if you have the same, please share